# How can I set environment variable for java jdk bin so that it shows same version in command prompt

Tags: java, installation, path, environment-variables, system-variable

I have set the Path variable in Environment Variables to C:\Java\jdk-15\bin which is the latest jdk I've recently downloaded from official Oracle site.

[image]

But, when I try to check the Java version from any other directory, it shows the version as below:

[image]

I have tried running the same command from C:\ too. It shows the same. Is this how it is supposed to look or am I doing something wrong here? I have got couple of jdk versions already installed on the system. Could this be cause of the older versions lying around in the system? Should I have uninstalled older versions before installing jdk-15?

Comment: Path is searched left to right (or top to bottom)... the very first entry in your picture is an older Java. Move jdk-15 to the top. Simple as that. BTW, Zookeeper doesn't support Java 15.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I think I may have to uninstall JDK-15 then, cause I want zookeeper too. Thanks for the suggestion.